# Getting last 5 leave requests for a user - where does the code live

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I have a User model, a user has_many leave_requests, in the user model I have the following code to find the last 5 leave requests:

```
  def last_five_leave_requests
    leave_requests.order(:updated_at).limit(5).reverse
  end
```

I kind of feel this code should live in the LeaveRequest model, what is the Rails way here to structure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in leave_request.rb:

```
scope :last_five, -> { order(updated_at: :desc).limit(5) }
```

And you can use:

```
LeaveRequest.last_five
model_that_has_many_leave_requests.last_five
```